# Theorem about the subgroup of a Lie group fixed by an involution

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

When trying to do Lie-theoretic calculations on Lie groups (finding the Bruhat decomposition, etc.) I've often come across expositions that seem to be implicitly using a result something like the following:

> Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H < G$ be a subgroup such that $H = G^\sigma$ (the points of $G$ fixed by $\sigma$), where $\sigma$ is an involution of $G$.  Let $T$ be a maximal torus, and $B$ be a Borel subgroup containing $T$, such that $B$ and $T$ and $\sigma$-stable.  Then $T^\sigma$ and $B^\sigma$ are a maximal torus and Borel subgroup of $H$, respectively.

For instance, something like this is done in Lakshmibai and Billey, *Singular Loci of Schubert Varieties*.

**Question:** What is the actual statement of this result in its full generality?  What is the proof, and/or where is it written down?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am confused: take $G=\mathrm{GL}_n$, $B$ to be upper triangular invertible matrices, and $\sigma$ to be inverse transpose. Then $G^\sigma$ is $O_n$ but obviously $B^\sigma$ is not a Borel. What am I missing?

Comment: Oops!  I left out that $B$ and $T$ were supposed to be $\sigma$-stable.  I've put it in now.

Comment: I'm not sure how much this is true in full generality, but in the case where $G$ is reductive, this is a standard result in the theory of real group representations. A proof in this case can be found in, say, https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjS6s7MvfH9AhWzL0QIHTzCAzUQFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.utah.edu%2F~milicic%2FEprints%2Fhmsw2.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2HqEvrcau2NnmaCUxnH21z

Comment: I forgot to say that the result is contained in Lemma 6.16 of the reference I mentioned.